# best approach to have multiple object as a service result

Tags: java, oop

I have a java service that sends a JSON as a result.
my service depends on some condition creat a conversationVO object and converts it to JSON and in the other condition create a participantVO object and convert it to JSON and finally, it sends/returns the JSON object as a result.
the question is that is it rational that my service sends different objects as a result? is this approach correct? or it's better that I create another VO, for example, resultVO object that has 2 fields of conversationVO and participantVO and it the conditions I fill one of 2 fields and finally send the JSON of new resultVO?

you can find codes below.

```
     public static void getThreadInfo(User currentUser, String uniqueName, long senderPeerId, String contactType, String uniqueId) {
    try (HibernateSession session = SessionManager.openSession()) {
        if (uniqueName == null || uniqueName.isEmpty()) {
            throw new ChatException(ChatException.UNIQUE_NAME_IS_NEEDED, "UNIQUE_NAME_IS_NEEDED. " + uniqueId);
        }
        User participant = UserCRUD.getUserByUsername(uniqueName, session);
        if (participant != null && participant.isActive()) {
            sendParticipantThreadInfo(currentUser, participant, senderPeerId, uniqueId);
        } else {
            sendThreadInfo(currentUser,uniqueName, contactType, senderPeerId, uniqueId, session);
        }
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        logger.warn("An exception occured", e);
        ControllerHelper.sendError(
                uniqueId,
                new Long[]{senderPeerId},
                e);
    }
}


private static void sendParticipantThreadInfo(User currentUser, User participant, long senderPeerId, String uniqueId) {
        ParticipantVO participantVO = ServiceHelper.fillParticipantSummary(participant);
        ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage();
        chatMessage.setType(ChatMessage.GET_THEAD_INFO);
        chatMessage.setContent(JsonUtil.getJson(participantVO));
        chatMessage.setUniqueId(uniqueId);
        chatMessage.setSubjectId(participant.getId());


        ControllerHelper.sendMessage(
                new ResultVO(
                        chatMessage,
                        Collections.singletonList(senderPeerId),
                        null,
                        true,
                        ChatSettings.MESSAGE_NORMAL_PRIORITY,
                        currentUser
                )
        );
}

private static void sendThreadInfo(User currentUser,
                                   String uniqueName,
                                   String contactType,
                                   long senderPeerId,
                                   String uniqueId,
                                   HibernateSession session) {
    try {
        MessageThread messageThread = getThreadByUniqueName(uniqueName, contactType, session);
        if (messageThread == null) {
            throw new ChatException(ChatException.USER_NOT_FOUND, "User or thread not found! " + uniqueId);
        }
        ConversationVO conversationVO = ServiceHelper.fillConversation(messageThread,
                null,
                true,
                false,
                contactType, session);

        ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage();
        chatMessage.setSubjectId(messageThread.getId());
        chatMessage.setContent(JsonUtil.getJson(conversationVO));
        chatMessage.setType(ChatMessage.GET_THEAD_INFO);
        chatMessage.setUniqueId(uniqueId);

        ControllerHelper.sendMessage(
                new ResultVO(
                        chatMessage,
                        Collections.singletonList(senderPeerId),
                        null,
                        true,
                        ChatSettings.MESSAGE_NORMAL_PRIORITY,
                        currentUser
                )
        );
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        logger.warn("An exception occured", e);
        ControllerHelper.sendError(
                uniqueId,
                new Long[]{senderPeerId},
                e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NewResultVO<T>{
  private String code;
  private T data; // T is your ResultVO or other VO.
}
```

Client get code "0000000" to do ...

Client get code "9999999" to do ...

Answer (score 0):

Better Approach is send data in a single result like below format.

**`JSON` Result**

```
{
  "ChatId": 1,
  "Description": "test",
  "conversation": [
    {
      "conversationId":1,
      "conversationType":"content"
    },
    {
       "conversationId":2,
      "conversationType":"content"
    }
  ],
   "participant": [
    {
      "participantId":1,
      "participantName":"Name1"
    },
    {
       "conversationId":2,
       "participantName":"Name2"
    }
  ]

}
```